# Almost in past events

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Can "almost" be used in the all tenses?

I give you the examples for "almost".

1. She has *almost* forgot about her cake and the presents.
2. She had *almost* forgot about her cake and the presents.
3. She *almost* forgot about her birthday cake and the presents.
4. She *almost* forgets about ....(the same as the above)..
5. She will/would have *almost* forgot...
6. She will/would *almost* forget ..
7. She was *almost* forgetting about..
8. She is *almost* forgetting about.
9. She will be *almost* forgetting about..

Are they possible in English, and could you tell me the differences between them?

I await for your explanation, thanks!

Comment: BTW, you "*wait for* an explanation" or "*await* an explanation".   "Await for" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Note that you should use he past participle after has/had/have: the past participle of forget is forgotten. This should be used in sentences 1, 2 ,5. If the simple past doesn't end with -ed, the past participle is probably irregular was well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

*Almost X* simply means we were close to doing X, but X did not happen, is not happening, or will not happen, depending on the tense.

It adds the idea of "close to X but didn't X" to any meaning when you construct a verb in English with modals or tense changes.

*Almost* can also just mean "incomplete" and the word position can change the meaning.

> She will forget about it = In the future, she  will 100% forget about it.
>
> She almost will forget about it = She was close to forgetting about it, but in the future, she will not forget about it.
>
> She will almost forget about it = Right now she remembers everything.  In the future, she will forget about it, but not completely forget all of it. 
>    She will still remember a portion of it.